# 'Bullet' object has no attribute '_Sprite__g' when adding Sprite to Group

Tags: python, pygame

I wrote a simple game in Python and I got an  error.

```
import pygame
import random
BLACK = (   0,   0,   0)
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)
RED   = ( 255,   0,   0)
BLUE  = (   0,   0, 255)
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 15])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 20])
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self):
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.rect.x = pos[0]
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.Surface([4, 10])
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y -= 3
pygame.init()
screen_size = [700,500]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Shooting things - Vers 2.0 of Blocks")
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
blocks_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range(50):
    block = Block(BLUE)
    block.rect.x = random.randrange( 660)
    block.rect.y = random.randrange( 480)

    blocks_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)
player = Player()
all_sprites_list.add(player)
score = 0
player.rect.y = 670
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            bullet = Bullet()
            bullet.rect.x = player.rect.x
            bullet.rect.y = player.rect.y
            all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
            bullets_list.add(bullet)
    all_sprites_list.update()

    for bullet in bullets_list:
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, blocks_list, True)

        for block in block_hit_list:
            bullets_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
            score += 1
            print(score)
        if bullet.rect.y <-10:
            bullets_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\KHAI NHANH PC\Desktop\My Stuff\Python\Shooting things.py", line 57, in <module>
    all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 360, in add
    sprite.add_internal(self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 163, in add_internal
    self.__g[group] = 0
AttributeError: 'Bullet' object has no attribute '_Sprite__g'
```

I checked line 57 and I still don't know what went wrong.
Line 57:

> ```
> all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
> ```

Comment: Check the versions, maybe there's a different version of pygame

Answer (score 6):

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
##You did not add this line below 
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10,20))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.speedy = -10
```

You need to remember that when you derive a new class you must call the .**init**(self) from your own class. So after you call your Bullet class you need to add:  pygame.sprite.Sprite.**init**(self) : after that as you probably did for your other classes.

http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/SpriteIntro.html

Comment: your answer is correct, but i you need to re-word it.

Comment: Yeah man. The only reason I said that, is that you didn't mention he needed to initialize the Pygame Sprite class.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing the Super call in your Bullet **init**.

```
Try:
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() #adding super call to make Bullet a pygame Sprite
        self.image = pygame.Surface([4, 10])
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y -= 3
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, classes `Block`, `Player` and `Bullet` inherit from `pygame.sprite.Sprite`. However you call the `super().__init__()` method only in `Block` and `Player`, you are missing calling the method also in Bullet.

Add the line `super().__init__()` to your class `Bullet`.

**Before:**

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.Surface([4, 10])
```

**After:**

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # Line to be added
        self.image = pygame.Surface([4, 10])
```

By the way, try to check something about [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is put

```
super().__init__()
```

after your constructor.