# Attribute Error: Object has no attribute '_Sprite__g' , while creating alien invasion

Tags: python, pygame, python-class

I was creating Alien invasion and I encountered this error of " object has no attribute '_sprite__g', please help me

```
class Game():
def __init__(self, screen, screen_height, screen_width):
    self.dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    
    self.display_message(screen,"Enter name", 50, WHITE, 600,500)
    pygame.display.flip()
    self.name = input("Enter your name")
    self.player_unshield_image = self.image('Traveller.png',75,75)
    self.player_shield_image = self.image('Zhongli.png',75,75)
    
    self.green_slave = self.image('Sara.png', 30,30)
    self.blue_slave = self.image('Yae.png',30,30)
    self.grey_slave =self.image('Itto.png',50,50)
    self.purple_slave = self.image('Raiden.png',120,120)
    
    self.fireball =self.image('Bullet.png',20,40)
    self.mango =self.image('YellowBullet.png',30,80)
    self.sun = self.image('OrangeBullet.png', 20,90)
    self.bullet_dict ={None:self.fireball, 'WideBullet':self.mango, 'PierceBullet':self.sun}

    self.powerup_wide =self.image('THICC.png',30,30)
    self.powerup_pierce =self.image('Pierce.png',30,30)
    self.powerup_shield =self.image('Noelle.png',30,30)
    self.powerup_add_score = self.image('Extra.png',30,30)
    
    self.high_score = 0

    self.shoot = self.sound('Pew.wav')
    self.explode =self.sound('BOOM_BOOM_BAKUDAN.wav')

    self.reset()

def reset(self):
    self.normal =(2,1, self.green_slave)
    self.tank =(1,2,self.blue_slave)
    self.rock =(5,3, self.grey_slave)
    self.boss =(7,10, self.purple_slave)

    self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    self.Slaves = pygame.sprite.Group()
    self.Ammo = pygame.sprite.Group()
    self.Powerup =pygame.sprite.Group()

    self.game_active =False
    self.Score = 0
    self.ammo_powerup =None
    self.Max_level =10
    self.level =0
    self.level_text_timer = 0
    self.max_ammo = 6
    self.ammo_num =self.max_ammo
    self.ammo_reload_timer = 0
    self.ammo_text =WHITE 
    self.game_played =False

    self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    self.clock.tick(FPS)
    self.player =Player(self.player_unshield_image, self.player_shield_image)
    self.all_sprites.add(self.player)

    for i in range(2) :
        powerup = Powerups(self.powerup_shield, self.powerup_pierce, self.powerup_add_score, self.powerup_wide)
        self.all_sprites.add(powerup)
        self.Powerup.add(powerup)
        

def image(self, image_name, width, height):
    image_dir =os.path.join(self.dir, 'Images')
    image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_dir, image_name)).convert()
    scaled_image =pygame.transform.scale(image,(width,height))
    return scaled_image

def sound(self, sound_name):
    sound_dir=os.path.join(self.dir, 'Sounds')
    return pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(sound_dir, sound_name))

def create_slaves(self, width, height, offset_a, offset_b, distance, slave_info):
    speed =slave_info[0]
    health =slave_info[1]
    slave_image =slave_info[2]
    for x in range (width):
        for y in range(height):
            d= Slaves(offset_a +x*distance, offset_b +y*distance, speed, health, slave_image)
            self.Slaves.add(d)
            self.all_sprites.add(d)

def display_message(self, surf, message, size, color, j, k):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", size)
    message_surface = font.render(message, True, color)
    message_rect = message_surface.get_rect()
    message_rect.midtop = (j, k)
    surf.blit(message_surface, message_rect)

def instructions(self):
    print('''Welcome to space invaders!
    Use Arrow keys to shoot, collect the coming powerups to gain special buffs
    figure out the point distribution yourself
    powerups include:
    pierce bullet, wide bullet, extra score addition
    the game has 10 levels, there are no extra lives
    last but most important, the game is over when you lose
    good luck!(probably)''')

def get_events(self, button):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            with open(os.path.join(self.dir, 'high_scores.txt'), 'a+') as score_file:
                score_file.write(self.name + "," + str(self.high_score)+ "," + (self.level)+ "\n")
            return False
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_SPACE and self.ammo_num > 0:
                img =self.bullet_dict[self.ammo_powerup]
                ammo = Ammo(self.player.rect.center, self.player.rect.top, self.ammo_powerup, img)
                self.ammo_powerup = None
                self.all_sprites.add(ammo)
                self.Ammo.add(ammo)
                self.ammo_num -=1
                self.shoot.play()
            else:
                pass
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_x, mouse_y =pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            self.check(button, mouse_x, mouse_y)
    return True

def check(self, button, x, y):
    clicked = button.rect.collidepoint(x,y)
    if clicked and not self.game_active:
        self.all_sprites.empty()
        self.Slaves.empty()
        self.Ammo.empty
        self.reset()
        self.game_active = True
        pygame.mouse.set_visible = False
        
def start(self):
    self.all_sprites.update()
    if len(self.Slaves) ==0:
        self.Ammo.empty()
        self.level +=1
        self.level_text_timer = 0
        if self.level ==1:
            self.create_slaves(10,5, 300, 40, 60, self.normal)
            self.game_played =True
        elif self.level ==2:
            self.create_slaves(10,4,300,45,60,self.normal)
            self.create_slaves(20,5, 400, 55,70, self.normal)
        elif self.level ==3:
            self.create_slaves(12,3,300,45,60, self.normal)
            self.create_slaves(20,5,400,55,70, self.normal)
            self.create_slaves(15,5,350,45,65, self.tank)
            self.max_ammo = 5
        elif self.level ==4 :
            self.create_slaves(13,4,300,45,65, self.normal)
            self.create_slaves(20,5,400,55,70, self.tank)
            self.create_slaves(15,5,400, 55,80, self.rock)
        elif self.level == 5:
            self.create_slaves(14,4,300,45,60, self.normal)
            self.create_slaves(11,3,250,35,60, self.normal)
            self.create_slaves(15,4,350,40,55, self.rock)
            self.create_slaves(13,5,400,35,65,self.rock)
        elif self.level == 6:
            self.create_slaves(12,4,300,45,60, self.normal)
            self.create_slaves(15,3,300,45,60, self.tank)
            self.create_slaves(15,4,350,35,50, self.rock)
            self.create_slaves(14,5,350,35,50, self.normal)
        elif self.level ==7:
            self.create_slaves(13,3,350,50,45, self.normal)
            self.create_slaves(15,3,300,45,60, self.tank)
            self.create_slaves(15,4,350,35,50, self.rock)
            self.create_slaves(17,4,400,45,50, self.rock)
        elif self.level ==8:
            self.create_slaves(12,4,300,45,60, self.normal)
            self.create_slaves(15,3,300,45,60, self.tank)
            self.create_slaves(15,4,350,35,50, self.rock)
            self.create_slaves(14,5,350,35,50, self.tank)
            self.create_slaves(12,3,300,45,55, self.normal)
        elif self.level == 9:
            self.create_slaves(16,3,300,45,60, self.tank)
            self.create_slaves(15,3,300,45,60, self.tank)
            self.create_slaves(15,4,350,35,50, self.rock)
            self.create_slaves(14,5,350,35,50, self.normal)
            self.create_slaves(16,7, 350,60,70, self.boss)
            self.max_ammo = 8
        elif self.level ==10:
            self.game_active =False
        self.ammo_num = self.max_ammo

    for slave in self.Slaves:
        attacks = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.player, slave)
        if attacks:
            slave.kill()
            if self.player.shielded:
                self.explode.play()
                self.player.unshield()
                self.Score += slave.worth

                if self.Score >self.high_score:
                    self.high_score = self.Score
            else:
                self.game_active =False
        if slave.rect.bottom > Height:
            self.game_active =False
        
        for ammo in self.Ammo:
            ammo_hit = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(ammo, slave)
            if ammo_hit:
                ammo_health_decrease = slave.slave_hp
                slave.slave_hp -= ammo.ammo_health
                ammo.ammo_health = ammo_health_decrease

                if ammo.ammo_health <= 0 :
                    ammo.kill()
                    
        for slave in self.Slaves:
            if slave.slave_hp <= 0:
                slave.kill()
                self. explode.play()
                self.Score +=slave.worth
                if self.Score > self.high_score:
                    self.high_score = self.Score
    
    for pu in  self.Powerup:
        hits_pu = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(pu, self.Ammo, False, False)

        if hits_pu:
            if pu.Powerup == 'shield':
                self.player.shield()
            elif 'ammo' in pu.powerup:
                self.ammo_powerup = pu.powerup
            elif pu.powerup == 'Score':
                self.Score += 5
                if self.Score >self.high_score:
                    self.high_score = self.Score
            pu.include_shield = not self.player.shielded
            pu.randomize()

    if self.ammo_num < self.max_ammo:
        self.ammo_reload_timer +=1
        if self.ammo_reload_timer >= 40 :
            self.ammo_num += 1
            self.ammo_reload_timer = 0
    
    if self.level >= self.Max_level:
        self.game_active = False

def display(self, screen, button):
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    if not self.game_active:
        if self.game_played:
            self.end_game(screen)
        button.draw_button()
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
    else:
        self.display_message(screen, "Score:" + str(self.Score), 28, BLUE, 110,110 )
        self.display_message(screen, "High Score:" + str(self.high_score), 30, ORANGE, 120,120)
        self.display_message(screen, "Level:" + str(self.level), 25, MAGENTA, 100,100)
        if self.ammo_powerup == None:
            self.ammo_text_color = WHITE
        elif self.ammo_powerup == 'WideBullet':
            self.ammo_text_color = ORANGE 
        elif self.ammo_powerup == 'PierceBullet':
            self.ammo_text_color = RED 
        self.display_message(screen, str(self.ammo_num) + "/" + str(self.ammo_reload_timer), 20, GRAY, 500,500)
        self.level_text_timer += 1
        if self.level_text_timer < 600 :
            self.display_message(screen, 'Level:' + str(self.level), 25, WHITE, 500,500 )
            self.level_text_timer += 1

    pygame.display.flip()

def end_game(self, screen):
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    self.display_message(screen, "YOU DIED!", 58, MAGENTA, 650,700)
    self.display_message(screen, "Final Score:" + str(self.Score), 30, ORANGE, 450,500)
    self.display_message(screen, "High Score:" + str(self.high_score), 40, CYAN, 500,550)
    self.display_message(screen, "Higest Floor Reached:" + str(self.level) + "/" +str(self.Max_level), 30, WHITE, 500,500)
```

here is the Screenshot of the error:

[This is the picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJNP1.png)

Any suggestions are helpful, please help

**The Error is present in "def create_Slaves()" and on the line, self.Slaves.add(d)**

Comment: I believe this might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/37780639/17936326. It mentions that you must call `super().__init__()` on any subclass of e.g. `pygame.sprite.Sprite`. Perhaps this also applies to your "Slaves" class?

Comment: We need a [mre]. The indentation here is wrong, the code doesn't raise any errors, and there is not even the code for the `Slaves` class which is obviously the root of the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this in your **init** function

```
class Game(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__((self, screen, screen_height, screen_width):
        super(Sprite, self).__init__()
```

Maybe your only problem is that you have to call it from the parent function

Comment: Yes, it works, I missed pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) line in slaves class,
Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: Your welcome bro @darkblader, please, just mark the answer correctly, so that others may face this problem in the future.

Comment: @Matin I don't think this answer is fully correct, however. The `super()` should be in the Slaves class, which the question author did not include in their question.

Comment: how do I mark it?

Comment: You are right @TomAarsen, but maybe this will happen again and someone will make such a mistake in the future

Comment: Just like this steps bro @darkblader , https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Hey, I have  one more problem, Once  I run the game, everything is fine, no errors, but after I click start , it shows no sprite, not the player or monster, only the bullet sound can be heard when I fire it. also the bullet counter and the high score, score, level are visible, only sprites are missing

Comment: Hey bro @darkblader, thanks for answer is helpful, and please can I see the modified version of your code, I want the whole codedark blader

Comment: umm, where can I post it? sorry I am new here so I don't know much

Comment: I have posted it on reddit, here is the link:
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/sar0y8/help_with_graphics_appearing_in_game/
thanks again

Comment: Bro @darkblader, can you tell me what library these Colors are?

Comment: oh sorry, fault, sorry, I created that module, I will send it to you rn

Comment: bro, @Matin, there you go , https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p2ZNT_NJyiI1GS4cpi8IwuHhgtYjBmqg/view?usp=sharing
the link is open, and  place the file in the same folder of daemon.py

Comment: bro @darkblader As far as I know your code, your bug is in two places and you have to fix it again, you put some items on top of each other in the game window, and you only have the image and the mode in your functions You specified their placement plus speed, blood and some features that you gave to the game but you for example like carImg = pygame.image.load ('racecar.png'), gameDisplay.blit (carImg, (x, y)) and did not specify their role and action time on the page, what to do about each reaction in each action, please review these sections again and test and correct the neighborhood

Comment: @darkblader and your events based on Describe how they work on the page, you can take a look at this simple example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-custom-events-in-pygame/

Comment: @Matin bro I will check it and correct the problem, hopefully it will work then

Comment: @darkblader I hope I was able to help you

Comment: @Matin, thanks to you the objects are appearing, but there is a problem with the collision in the rightmost line of the enemies which is unreachable and I think is stopping the enemies from moving, can you please take a look at it, I am sorry for disturbing ya

Comment: link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uc4qo2gqleRX7UGlD9dESe3Wb8FL1m-k?usp=sharing
 just run daemon.py , it is the main file.
if possible can you also give the fix, I have tried to fix this alot but not, working for me.
and yes, pilot is out of screen, I am working on that. the bullet will still fire on pressing space and movement from left and right key

Comment: updated link:https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10fEbzH4ijQKO_KJFSAHk39gb8fqIk8HY?usp=sharing
I have fixed the powerups and pilot only the movement is causing problem, now they are moving but only to one side and not coming back please help

Comment: i will check it soon